# How can we get the "inputs" context from within a javascript GitHub action?

Tags: node.js, github-actions, github-api

I'm using the [`github-script` action](https://github.com/actions/github-script/) to use some javascript for some tasks in my workflow.

If I use a workflow with the `workflow_dispatch` trigger for example, I can get its inputs via `context.payload.inputs`.

I'm making use of [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows), so I have a workflow with the `workflow_call` trigger, and then another workflow that calls that one, via `jobs.<job>.uses`.

When using templating in workflow files, a `workflow_dispatch` input is referenced like `${{ github.event.inputs.<input_name> }}` but to reference the inputs to a `workflow_call`, we just use `${{ inputs.<input_name> }}`. [That's all fine when templating the values](https://github.community/t/inconsistent-inputs-context-for-workflow-dispatch-and-workflow-call/207835), there's no issue there, but what I'm wondering is how I can directly get at that `inputs` context from within JS. I can't seem to find it and I haven't been able to find any examples.

Here's some snippets to demonstrate:

##### A `workflow_dispatch` example

```yaml
---
name: scripty
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      dummy:
        required: false
        description: dummy
jobs:
  scripty:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: script
        id: script
        uses: actions/github-script@v5
        with:
          script: |
            var dummy = context.payload.inputs.dummy
            return {
                context: context,
                github: github,
                env: process.env,
                test1: dummy
            }

      - run: |
          echo <<EOF
          ${{ toJSON(fromJSON(steps.script.outputs.result)) }}
          EOF
```

This works great!

##### A `workflow_call` workflow (the one that's reused)

```yaml
---
name: scripty-called
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      dummy:
        required: false
        description: dummy
jobs:
  scripty-called:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: script
        id: script
        uses: actions/github-script@v5
        with:
          script: |
            //var dummy = context.payload.inputs.dummy
            // ^ this will fail
            return {
                context: context,
                github: github,
                env: process.env
            }

      - run: |
          echo <<EOF
          ${{ toJSON(fromJSON(steps.script.outputs.result)) }}
          EOF
```

##### The calling workflow

```yaml
---
name: scripty-caller
on:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  scripty-caller:
    name: Call scripty
    uses: <my-repo>/.github/workflows/scripty-shared.yml@thisref
    with:
      dummy: '@DUMMY_VALUE@'
```

Now, I know in this example, I'm embedding the script in the workflow, so I could just template it:

```yaml
      - name: script
        id: script
        uses: actions/github-script@v5
        with:
          script: |
            var dummy = '${{ inputs.dummy }}'
            return {
                context: context,
                github: github,
                env: process.env
            }
```

But that feels wrong... and it will not work well if I want to put the script into a separate file in the repo, or if I want to graduate this snippet into a real JS-based action.

So I'm wondering, how can that value be accessed? And also, how could I have found the answer without posting? I've spent hours digging through code and docs and web posts, was there a better place to look?

Comment: When you put the script into a separate file, couldn't you supply the inputs as parameters when making the call to run that file? That's how I do that for actions that call shell scripts.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes I could, and if it were a separate action, then I could make that action take a parameter and force the end user to send in the input(s) needed (or something like `${{ toJSON(inputs) }}` if I need the whole thing), but that'd not be a good experience. In any case, I can workaround the issue for sure, but I am trying to figure out how this value could be accessed natively, or if it cannot, why not?

Comment: Then, how about [using `env:` to provide the inputs](https://github.com/actions/github-script#use-env-as-input)?

Comment: @BenjaminW. somewhat surprisingly given how it works and the limitations, the environment if the calling workflow is _not_ passed into the called workflow, so it's not possible to pass values that way. Since the called workflow is the entirety of what gets run (you can't combine it with other tasks in the calling workflow), that also rules out filesystem and such. Inputs are the supported method of passing values into a workflow call.

Comment: I meant putting it in the environment of the step in the job of the called workflow.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I see, yeah that's another workaround though. I'd have to serialize to preserve type info but that's the same with templating for non-string types. I appreciate the suggestions, but am more looking to know how to get at it natively, if it's possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting as answer to describe what I did, even though I never found an answer to my actual question. I won't mark this as an answer though, maybe it will be directly answerable someday.

In the end, I did have to just resort to templating.

What I opted to do instead of individually templating each input, is template `inputs` once so that I can get at all the inputs as a map, preserve type info.

```js
var inputs = ${{ toJSON(inputs) }}
var dummy = inputs['dummy']
```

What threw me off initially was that I was trying to put the serialized JSON into a string, and then deserialize it in the code, something like:

```js
// don't do this
var inputsJson = '${{ toJSON(inputs) }}'
var inputs = JSON.parse(inputsJson)
```

And this kept failing, due to the JSON being multi-line and such, and it took way too long for it to dawn on me that **JS**ON is valid JS; we could emded it and use it/assign it directly. It feels weird, but works very well.